# Return TEMPORARY TABLE as table in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-10

The scenario is simple. Define a set of results as `TEMPORARY TABLE`, use this in another query as its `IN` part and then, after all the queries are finished, return that `TEMPORARY TABLE`.

In my case, define the `delete_group`, use it in `DELETE` and then return the `delete_group`.

I came up with this

```
CREATE  FUNCTION update_delete_honda
(modelId bigint, hondaId bigint)
RETURNS TABLE
(id bigint,name text) 
AS $$
DECLARE
 var_r record;
BEGIN    

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE delete_group (honda_id bigint,name text)
ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO delete_group (honda_id,name)
SELECT honda_id,name FROM car WHERE service_id is null and drive_id is null;


 EXECUTE format(
   'UPDATE car SET model_Id = null WHERE honda_Id=$1'
) USING modelId , hondaId;

DELETE FROM suv WHERE id  IN (select honda_id from delete_group);

 FOR var_r IN(delete_group)  
 LOOP
   id := honda_id ; 
   name := name ;
   RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This does not work. I get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "delete_group"`
about the `FOR var_r IN(delete_group)` line.

How do I fix this?  I use PostgreSQL 10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to

`FOR var_r IN SELECT * FROM delete_group` ,

and use `suv.id` (instead of just `id`) in

`DELETE FROM suv WHERE suv.id  IN (select honda_id from delete_group);`

You provided no definition of the tables car and suv, so I can't be sure if the function really does what you want it to ... but the above should be correct syntax.

Comment: I did  `FOR var_r IN SELECT * FROM delete_group
 LOOP
   id := honda_id ; 
   name := name ;
   RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;` and I get `ERROR:  column "honda_id" does not exist` . I tried `FOR var_r IN (SELECT * FROM delete_group)` , same error. I also tried 
`FOR var_r IN (SELECT * FROM delete_group)
 LOOP
   id := delete_group.honda_id ; 
   name := delete_group.name ;
   RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP;`  and get `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "delete_group"` Thanks

Comment: Hm, have you tried `id := var_r.honda_id ; name := var_r.name`?